# Surprising class definition scope behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have some function:

```
def f(x):
    return x
```

...and some class definition using it, like so:

```
class Cgood():
    x = None
    y = f('foo')
```

This works fine:

```
>>> Cgood().y
'foo'
```

However, if I try to do something like this:

```
class Cbad():
    x = None
    y = [f(x) for _ in 'abcdefg']
```

We get an error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why is `x` not available in the scope of the list comprehension? Is there some other way to access `x`? The only way I see is ditching the list comp and resorting to a normal `for` loop.

EDIT: I am on Python 3.6.2

Comment: List comprehension or `for` loop both have no own scope, so Cbad should be working like Cgood do.

Comment: @A.Haaji I agree. Sadly, it doesn't.

Comment: i just tried to run your example and i got 
`Out[3]: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`
for 
`In [3]: Cbad.y`

Comment: Isn't it like there must be an operation of the iterator variable on the left side of the for-in loop and not some other variable?

Comment: Also check the explanation under: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

Comment: Good lord I swear I searched before posting this! Thanks for the link @AshwiniChaudhary.

Comment: In Python 3, list comprehensions are now implemented with a function (which has its own scope) that is called to produce the list value. This makes them work the same as generator expressions,